# VB Script ignore special character

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

any idea how to ignore a < or > in a VBS string ie:

```
strEx = "<10 days"
response.write(strEx)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try thing instead:-

```
Response.Write(Server.HTMLEncode(strEx))
```

This will correctly escape characters that have meaning to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

By ignore, do you mean remove? If so try this:

```
strEx = replace("<10 days", "<", "")
```

Or if you'd like to write your string on to a webpage, you can encode the `<` to have it outputted correctly:

```
strEx = replace("<10 days", "<", "&lt;")
```

Comment: Thanks, Ideally I need to leave the string as it is. I've thought of using replace but I wondered if there's a way of escaping or ignoring the < character or using something like double quotes (obviously tried that and it doesn't work).